# CSS: @font-face import not working

Tags: css, text, fonts, import

I don't understand how to get this to work, any help would be appreciated;

I'm going off of what I got from this website: http://alistapart.com/article/cssatten

from my style.css

```
@font-face {
 font-family: "JSL";
 src: url(http://ff.static.1001fonts.net/j/s/jsl-ancient.normal.ttf) format("truetype");
}

font {
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 120%;
 font-family: "JSL";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither is the plus sign the issue (tested with my renamed fonts), nor do you have to import a separate css file at the top of your main css file.

However, you may need to have more versions of your font than just the true type. Have a look at [Bulletproof @font-face Syntax](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/).

You may use [FontSquirrel’s generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to achieve this.

Here is an example of a `@font-face` embed in my application, which is pinned right at the top of my main css stylesheet.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'JustVector';
    src: url('../fonts/justvectorv2+webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/justvectorv2+webfont.eot?') format('eot'),
        url('../fonts/justvectorv2+webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/justvectorv2+webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/justvectorv2+webfont.svg#webfontkw9J4lGf') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Also, check your console to make sure that the font you're hotlinking isn't giving you a 403 Forbidden when you make the request.

Comment: I tried this, does this have to be done server-side? Because this is still not working for me

Answer (score 0):

no

```
@font-face
```

Try get inport it:

```
@import_your_new_cssfile.css
```

whre you put:

```
font-face {
 font-family: "JSL";
 src: url(http://www.fontyukle.net/en/DownLoad-JSL+Ancient.ttf) format("truetype");
}

font {
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 120%;
 font-family: "JSL";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is perhaps the "+" sign in the font URL a problem? You might want to URL encode it.

Edit - after hitting the font URL, it looks like you should try to download the ttf file, and refer to it locally, rather than from a remote source. It's prompting me for a Captcha in order to download the file, which is probably why it's not working.

Comment: I realized this after I posted it, but I changed the link to http://ff.static.1001fonts.net/j/s/jsl-ancient.normal.ttf with the same result

Answer (score 0):

You do need to download the file and refer to it locally, 
The link supported there is a download link and requires a Captcha to be downloaded which means it is NOT a direct link to the TTF File.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Font you may need to use:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'someFont';
src: url('path/to/font/someFont.eot');
src: url('path/to/font/someFont.eot?#iefix'), format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('path/to/font/someFont.woff'), format('woff'), 
     url('path/to/font/someFont.ttf'), format('truetype'), 
     url('path/to/font/someFont.svg'), format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

and in CSS:

```
BODY 
{
    font-family: 'someFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    ... 
}
```

This worked for me when I had issues wityh embedding a custom font.